# Event handling in PrimeNG

Tags: angular, primeng

Tell me, please, where to find examples of event processing in PrimeNG.
Well, I do not know what to write instead of XXX.

```
<p-dropdown (onChange)="onChangeCity(XXX)"...></p-dropdown>
...
...
onChangeCity(XXX){
...
}
```

Comment: You're supposed to have a ngModel in your dropdown. Send it to your function.

Comment: (onChange)="onChangeCity($event)" and inside ts file write onChangeCity(event)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Event processing is done so

```
<p-dropdown (onChange)="onChangeCity($event)"...></p-dropdown>
...
...
onChangeCity(event){
let changedValue = event.value;
let domEvent = event.originalEvent;
...
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use 'onDblClick' event for <p-listbox> and the event object has only this value {"originalEvent":{"isTrusted":true}}. Any idea how to get the selected item value?